# Customize Bulma in Angular

Tags: angular, bulma

I'm trying to customize Bulma's colors in an Angular project:
To do so, I import the initial variables file from the bulma package into my /src/styles.scss file, override the desired variable, then import the rest of bulma as the docs reccomend to do: https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-sass-cli/

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/initial-variables";

// Override desired variables
$primary: darkorange;

// Import the rest of Bulma
@import "../node_modules/bulma/bulma";
```

The problem is that my changes are overriden:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3C6UJ.png)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you replace the contents of your styles.scss with the SASS from step 6 of the link, are the changes still overwritten? If so, then you are probably importing bulma uncustomized somewhere else in your app. If not, though, then it would seem that what you have written here is not correctly structured, so maybe you should simply change the values of the variables in the now-working file to whatever you want.

Comment: @marsnebulasoup, you're right! i was importing in angular.json both bulma and styles.scss, thanks